Uniqueness of idiosyncratic error in factor model
I have been learning about the uniqueness problem of idiosyncratic error $\sum$, and found two relevant references:
Anderson and Rubin, 1956:

Bekker and ten Berge, 1997:

The result from Bekker and ten Berge seems to be less restrictive than the one from Anderson and Rubin? How do I understand these two theorems from the point of application? I think there might be subtle difference in the two theorems.
Thanks!
